# bootstrap collapse stacking elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4.0.0 collapse to hide and reveal a bootstrap "row". The row contains four columns - "col-md-3" - of buttons. This row is laying out just as I want it too until I add the "collapse" class, which then causes all the cols inside the row to stack like block elements.

Is this a known thing, that you can't put a row, or complex elements to be collapsed?

Below are two screenshots of before and after - with the element html visible on the :[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoaBL.jpg)

[After:bad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kp495.jpg)

Comment: Also noticing why is there an empty style attribute that gets inserted for no reason by bootstrap. That seems buggy.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have [**tried so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: The images do that very well - clearly showing the page and the html. So far I have tried doing it the way its supposed to be done, and the results are bad. I also tried wrapping the row in a plain div with no luck.

Comment: I think this is as minimal and complete as can be. Does adding the bootstrap "collapse" class cause changes to elements within the target?

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: adding the collapse class doesn't, it just changes the height and width properties from fixed to fluid. when that happens since there is not a  container div between the collapse, the col-md divs adjust to the closes parent fixed container. in your example you linked, putting an extra div in and collapsing that instead of the row tag that should be inside of that div tag. Also, you might need to assign class=container in the added div

Comment: I also suggest to post your code instead of linking it. Only some have zoom that will see your screen shot clearly.

Comment: I found this: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/22600 which seems to be the same issue, somethign about collapse disabling flexbox. I adde the css snippet and it worked.
.collapse {
  display: none;
  &.show {
    display: block;
  }
  &.row.show {
    display: flex;
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

well the col-*-* css is a flexible container, that has padding and margin settings that change with screen size. There will be some elements that will be blank depending on screen size. When I build a menu I use fixed elements inside the collapse using ul and li tags like you would a nav bar. I have used the navbar code, then override colors inline by setting style attributes in the html tag. Also, you can dynamically insert display:none in an element via jquery or java might give you a better effect (which I use from time to time instead of the collapse routine bootstrap has set up.. ). You can also play with inserting offset-md-*  class in if you just need to offset a div container. But I use that for centering a responsive div like a login screen.